# How to capture click outside React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I started to learn React and I am trying to implement a modal window. I am at the same time using TypeScript.

I wanted to capture a click outside my React component, so when I click outside the modal window, this one closes. I based my approach on this: [How to capture click outside React component](https://medium.com/@pitipatdop/little-neat-trick-to-capture-click-outside-react-component-5604830beb7f)

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledModal = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.625rem, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    width: 32rem;
  },
`;

class Modal extends React.Component<ModalProps> {
    private modal: HTMLDivElement;

    onOutsideClick = (e: any) => {
      if (!_.isNil(this.modal)) {
        if (!this.modal.contains(e.target)) {
          this.onClose(e);
        }
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onOutsideClick, false);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.onOutsideClick, false);
    }

    render() {
        <div>
            <StyledModal ref={(node: any) => { this.modal = node; }}>
            ...
            </StyledModal>
        </div>
    }
}
```

The issue is whenever I click inside or outside the modal I get this error, which I don't know what it is or how to fix it:

[image]

Any lights please let me know...

Comment: can you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) for your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your StyledModal is `styled-components` you need to add innerRef to be able to get the DOM node. Keep in mind innerRef is a custom prop only for `styled-components`

https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/docs/tips-and-tricks.md#refs-to-dom-nodes

```
<StyledModal innerRef={(node: any) => { this.modal = node; }}>
  ...
</StyledModal>
```

Comment: StyledModal is not a custom component is just a styled component. Please check my updated code snippet

Comment: I believe you just need to add innerRef instead.

Comment: I edited my answer to for you. styled-components is a wrapper over the DOM Nodes so you need to use innerRef instead of ref.

Answer (score 0):

From styled-components v4 onward it is `ref` prop.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.inputRef = React.createRef();
}

render() {
  return (
   <Input
      ref={this.inputRef}
    />
  );
}
```

For more info [Refs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#refs)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a tiny component (466 Byte gzipped) that already exists for this functionality then you can check out this library [react-outclick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-outclick). It lets you capture clicks outside of a component.

The good thing about the library is that it also lets you detect clicks outside of a component and inside of another. It also supports detecting other types of events.